# Azure sql server size resets to 1GB

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am working on a Web application based on EF with over 1 GB seeded data. The application is hosted in Azure with Bizspark subscription account.

I created a App Service Plan with the Web application associated with an App Service sometime back. I started uploading data to Sql Server but this failed. I realized that the default size was 1GB so I upgraded the plan to a Standard Plan with 10 DTU and 10 GB yesterday and uploaded the data around 5 days back.

After which I due to certain issues, I wiped out the App Service Plan and created a new one. SQL Server size and setup was not modified.

I created a new plan and uploaded the application and observed the following -

1. Database tables got wiped out
2. Database prizing structure was reset to Basic

I upgraded the database plan once again to 10 GB and 10 DTU yesterday night. I see that the change has not taken affect yet.

3. How long does it take get the size fixed?
4. Will the tables have to be recreated?

9/11
I just tried uploading data via `bcp` tool. But I got the following error:

1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 51000
Communication link failure
Text column data incomplete
Communication link failure
TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
Communication link failure

This is new as yesterday before I changed the db size I got the following error: 
9/10

1000 rows sent to SQL Server. **Total sent: 1454000**
**The database 'db' has reached its size quota**. Partition or delete data, drop indexes, or consult the documentation for possible resolutions.
BCP copy in failed

I don't understand the inconsistency in the failure message or even that the upload failed for the same data file.

Regards,
Lalit

Comment: Are you using a code first approach, maybe with the deploy the database was re-created.

Answer (score 0):

Scaling up a database to a higher service tier should not take more than a few minutes from Basic to Standard. The schemas and table inside the database are left unchanged.

You may want to look into the Activity log of your Azure server to understand who initiated the scale down from Standard to Basic. Furthermore, you may want to turn on the Auditing feature to understand all the operations that are performed on your database.

On connectivity issues, you can start looking at this [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-troubleshoot-common-connection-issues). It also looks like you have inserted rows several times into your database through the BCP command and this causes a space issue for the Basic tier.